# Run script that is saved inside an object as a string

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains a string which is actually a script.

```
forms = {
    "528": {
        "thankyou_page_url": "",
        "external_url": "http:\/\/example.com",
        "use_external_url": "on",
        "open_in_new_tab": "",
        "after_sent_script": "alert( 'test script' );"
    },
};
```

I want to run the `alert` function from `after_sent_script`, inside another function. Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (form.after_sent_script) {
        form.after_sent_script;
    }
});
```

This of course does not work.

How can it be done?

Comment: You have to save it as a function, not a string http://jsfiddle.net/29sVC/1299/

Comment: Did you try eval

Comment: Thanks Amit, that works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (form.after_sent_script) {
        eval(form.after_sent_script);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`, but you can read up why you should be cautious using `eval`.

```js
var forms = {
    "528": {
        "thankyou_page_url": "",
        "external_url": "http:\/\/example.com",
        "use_external_url": "on",
        "open_in_new_tab": "",
        "after_sent_script": "alert( 'test script' );"
    },
};

eval(forms['528']['after_sent_script']);
```